# New to Python, creating a craps game when given n games

Tags: python

I'm new to programming, and particular python, and I'm having trouble with a problem I have for homework.

Here's the problem:

Craps is a dice-based game played in may casinos. Like blackjack, a player plays against the house. The game starts with the player throwing a pair of standard, six-sided dice. If the player rolls a total of 7 or 11, the player wins. If the player rolls a total of 2, 3, or 12, the player loses. For all other roll values, the player will repeatedly roll the pair of dice until either she rolls the initial value again (in which case she wins) or 7 (in which case she loses)

Implement function testCraps() that takes a positive integer n as input, simulates n games of craps, and returns the fraction of games the player won.

```
>>> testCraps(1000)
0.4844

>>> testCraps(1000)
0.492
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
import random

def roll():
   dice = (random.randrange(1,7) + random.randrange (1,7))
   return dice

def testCraps(n):
    dice = roll()
    total = 0
    count = 0

    for i in range (n):
        total = total + 1

        if dice == 2 or dice == 3 or dice == 12:
            count = count + 0
        elif dice == 7 or dice == 11:
            count += 1
        else:
            dice1 = roll()
             while dice1 != 7 or dice1 != dice:
                  if dice1 == 7:
                     count = count + 0
                  elif dice1 == dice:
                     count += 1
                  else: 
                     dice1 = roll()

     return(float(count/total))
```

Am I missing anything? Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? What should we look for?

Comment: My problem is that python runs and then it stops taking input. So I'm trying to figure out what I did wrong with my coding that stops it. testCraps(100)
1.0
>>> testCraps(300)

Comment: Do you get an error? Try placing print statements to see where your code stops.

Comment: no, it just doesn't give anything. I'll try that though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are experiencing a "Hang" in your program, or a loop forever situation which means it cannot complete exectuing.
You loop while `dice1 != 7 or dice1 != dice` which means the loop won't stop until dice1 is equal to both 7 and `dice`, which means that it'll loop forever if `dice` is not 7.

```
while dice1 != 7 or dice1 != dice:
```

Now a second problem, here's the fixed code with comments:

```
dice1 = roll()
while True: # Loop until either lost or won
    if dice1 == 7:
        break # Player lost, don't do anything
    elif dice1 == dice:
        count += 1 # Player won, increase count
        break
    else:
        dice1 = roll()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is messed up.

Starting at the line

```
for i in range (n):
```

This code is no longer part of the function "testcraps()".

That may not be the only thing wrong, but definitely start by getting the indentation correct.

The indentation has been fixed so I'll edit my answer.

I'm not going to write code for your homework but I'll give you this advice. Your problems now are "logical" ones. You need to break the problem down into simpler steps that you can understand and test more easily. Start by writing a function which simulates just a **single** game and returns 0/1 (or True/False if you prefer) depending on whether that game is won or lost. Get that working an the rest will be trivial.

Comment: Opps! It's right in the program, just copied wrong.

Comment: Then we're into the "other problems". But please edit your code so that it truly reflects what you're running. Otherwise no one can really help you.

Comment: That's better. The indentation of your return is still wrong, but at least it's close enough now that we can guess what you intended.